# Black-Scholes differential equation rewritten

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, black-scholes-pde, differential-equations

I have seen that the Black-Scholes equation

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}+
rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}-rV=0$$

can also be written in the following form:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial S} \left( \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)+\left(rS-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\right)\right)\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}-rV=0. $$

How are the following two terms equal?

$$ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}+
rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial}{\partial S} \left( \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)+\left(rS-\frac{\partial}{\partial S}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\right)\right)\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial S} \left( \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)
=\sigma^2S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+ \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2}
$$
The first term above cancels with the second term in the second bucket of brackets.

Comment: Daneel: I'm aware of my dense-ness ( or density but density has a different meaning ) but can you do me a favor. I understand the equation that you wrote but can you give more details on how that results in the second equation that Chris_J wrote ? Let me refer to Chris_J's equations as 1,2 and 3.  To me, it looks like, in 2,  the same thing is being added and subtracted and the second term of 1 is being left out ? But obviously, I'm confused. Thanks for any additional details and I'm sorry to take your time.

Comment: @markleeds in 2 as you say the same term is being added and subtracted, which is the 4th term in OP’s equation 2 and the first term in my equation. The second term in OP’s equation 1 is equal to the second term in my equation. So all adds up.

Comment: Got it now ( as I bang myself in the head ).  Thanks for your patience.